# locate customer signup code for register.phtml in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-account

A little background for myself; I am not php background but have a bit clarity of how Magento works. I am trying locate code behind file where customer gets created so that I may put some confition on it.

The code I located in register.phtml is below:

```
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
```

Here, I am completely clueless on $block->getPostActionUrl() ?> by this what code is getting called. So that I may intercept and condition the flow.

Can you guys give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this function in Magento_root/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Form/Register.php

[image]

If you look in register.phtml file you will get namespace in comment area in top of the page.
[image]
using that you can debug it.

If this helps you then hit like.

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: But, that doesn't have code to create the customer?